# Android - App crashes when button is clicked to show an activity with listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I have this code found around the net and decided to try it on my app if it's applicable. When the button is clicked it should show an activity when all the data from the database are being shown in the list view.

Here's the code:

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                    .getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                    .getText().toString();

            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SingleContactActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
            in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity5.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                    String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                    String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                    String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity5.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL,
                        TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                        R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}

}
```

Then here's the class where the button is located:

```
public class MainActivity3Activity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button ViewGradesActivity;
Button ClassScheduleActivity;
Button CalendarOfActivitiesActivity;
Button AccountBalanceActivity;
Button StudentProfileActivity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity3);


   ShowMainActivity= (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainactbutton);
   ShowMainActivity.setOnClickListener(this);

   ClassScheduleActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.classSched);
   ClassScheduleActivity.setOnClickListener(this);

    CalendarOfActivitiesActivity = (Button)   findViewById(R.id.activities);
    CalendarOfActivitiesActivity.setOnClickListener(this);

    AccountBalanceActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.balance);
    AccountBalanceActivity.setOnClickListener(this);

    StudentProfileActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.profile);
    StudentProfileActivity.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()) {
        //this is to show the activity with the list view
        case R.id.mainactbutton:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity5.class));
            break;
        case R.id.classSched:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,classSchedule.class));
            break;
        case R.id.activities:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,CalendarOfActivities.class));
            break;
        case R.id.balance:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,AccountBalance.class));
            break;
        case R.id.profile:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,StudentProfile.class));
            break;
    }
}

}
```

So whenever I click that `mainactbutton` the app crashes. What should I do? Is there something wrong with the activity with the list view?

Thank you for the help.

EDIT: Now that I have edited the manifest file and added the `MainActivity5` the app still crashed and here's the log:

```
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
        at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:277)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
        at com.example.kreshiathea.myfirstapp.MainActivity5.onCreate(MainActivity5.java:52)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
```

Here is my list view:

`activity_main5.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<!-- Main ListView 
     Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
-->
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Shadow  I've edited the post. Thank you for checking it out.

Comment: @mustafasevgi  I've edited the post. Thank you for checking it out.

Comment: @PiyushGupta  I've edited the post. Thank you for checking it out.

Comment: You must declare MainActivity5 class in AdnroidManifest.xml file

Comment: logcat cleanly shows everything..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare MainActivity5 class in AdnroidManifest.xml file

---

If you extends from ListActivity, then don't use setContentView(). You need get the default list view get by getListView().

```
Listview listview=getListView();
```

---

```
<ListView
 android:id="@android:id/list" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: I edited the manifest file but it crashed. I posted the logcat above.

Comment: @progRookie can you add which xml contains your listview?

Comment: I've posted the xml... please check it out.

Comment: I tried doing it but it still shows the same error.

Comment: So do i have to change from setContentView() to getListView()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73305/discussion-between-mustafasevgi-and-progrookie).

Answer (score 2):

> have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Every activity you use have to be declared in your manifest

```
      <activity
        android:name="com.example.kreshiathea.myfirstapp.MainActivity5"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        >
      </activity>
```

Comment: I edited the manifest file but it crashed. I posted the logcat above.

Comment: set  `android:id="@android:id/list"` for your `ListView` in xml file.

Comment: This also did a great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
this.startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity5.class));
```

& **have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?**

Comment: I don't think so the issue is because of this.

Comment: So now the problem was with context?

Comment: I edited the manifest file but it crashed. I posted the logcat above.